# underline text with odfpy

Tags: python, underline, odf, odfpy

I'd like to generate an odf file with odfpy, and am stuck on underlining text.
Here is a minimal example inspired from official documentation, where i can't find any information about what attributes can be used and where.
Any suggestion?

```
from odf.opendocument import OpenDocumentText
from odf.style import Style, TextProperties
from odf.text import H, P, Span

textdoc = OpenDocumentText()

ustyle = Style(name="Underline", family="text")
#uprop = TextProperties(fontweight="bold")                  #uncommented, this works well
#uprop = TextProperties(attributes={"fontsize":"26pt"})     #this either
uprop = TextProperties(attributes={"underline":"solid"})    # bad guess, wont work  !!
ustyle.addElement(uprop)
textdoc.automaticstyles.addElement(ustyle)
p = P(text="Hello world. ")
underlinedpart = Span(stylename=ustyle, text="This part would like to be underlined. ")
p.addElement(underlinedpart)
p.addText("This is after the style test.")
textdoc.text.addElement(p)
textdoc.save("myfirstdocument.odt")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I finally got it:

I created a sample document with underlining using libreoffice, and unzipped it. Looking in styles.xml part of the extracted files, I got the part that makes underlining in the document:

```
<style:style style:name="Internet_20_link" style:display-name="Internet link" style:family="text">
<style:text-properties fo:color="#000080" fo:language="zxx" fo:country="none" style:text-underline-style="solid" style:text-underline-width="auto" style:text-underline-color="font-color" style:language-asian="zxx" style:country-asian="none" style:language-complex="zxx" style:country-complex="none"/>
</style:style>
```

The interesting style attributes are named: text-underline-style,
text-underline-width and text-underline-color.

To use them in odfpy, '-' characters must be removed, and attributes keys must be used as str (with quotes) like in the following code. A correct style family (text in our case) must be specified in the Style constructor call.

```
from odf.opendocument import OpenDocumentText
from odf.style import Style, TextProperties
from odf.text import H, P, Span

textdoc = OpenDocumentText()

#underline style
ustyle = Style(name="Underline", family="text")  #here  style family

uprop = TextProperties(attributes={
    "textunderlinestyle":"solid",
    "textunderlinewidth":"auto",
    "textunderlinecolor":"font-color"
    })

ustyle.addElement(uprop)
textdoc.automaticstyles.addElement(ustyle)
p = P(text="Hello world. ")
underlinedpart = Span(stylename=ustyle, text="This part would like to be underlined. ")
p.addElement(underlinedpart)
p.addText("This is after the style test.")
textdoc.text.addElement(p)

textdoc.save("myfirstdocument.odt")
```